# How can I get rid of a white screen after a splash screen in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, cordova-plugins

How can I get rid of a white screen after a splash screen in ionic 2?

@peka. I have tried severally but it stills give me a white screen after splash screen. Best Regards

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen,SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp{
  rootPage = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();

      let db = new SQLite();
      db.openDatabase({
        name: "data.db",
        location: "default"
      }).then(() => {
        db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)", {}).then((data) => {
          console.log("TABLE CREATED: ", data);
        }, (error) => {
          console.error("Unable to execute sql", error);
        })
      }, (error) => {
        console.error("Unable to open database", error);
      });
    });
  }
```

}

Comment: Can you provide any code examples when this happens? Are you testing native or

Comment: @Jari Pekkala see the edited question

Comment: Anyone who can help?

Comment: Does this happen with a fresh project? $ ionic start myApp tabs --v2

Answer (score 0):

Add the following preference to your config.xml in your root directory:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

Disabling `AutoHideSplashScreen` overrides `SplashScreenDelay`, when platform is ready, `Splashscreen.hide()` will take in effect.

reference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#configxml